# RabbitMQ & php-amqplib - Message not being delivered to consumer

Tags: php, centos, rabbitmq

Setup: Centos 6.2, RabbitMQ 3.1.3, PHP 5.4.3

I am attempting to run the demo scripts from [php-amqlib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib), specifically
amqp_consumer_non_blocking.php & amqp_publisher.php

In one console I run 'php amqp_consumer_non_blocking.php', in another 'php amqp_publisher.php This is a test'

'amqp_consumer_non_blocking.php' sits waiting with:

```
< 60,20: Basic.consume
waiting for 60,21
waiting for a new frame
> 60,21: Basic.consume_ok
```

and 'amqp_publisher.php' produces this:

```
< 60,40: Basic.publish
< [hex]:
0000  02 00 01 00 00 00 1A 00  3C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ <.......
0010  00 00 0E 90 00 0A 74 65  78 74 2F 70 6C 61 69 6E   .....te xt/plain
0020  02 CE                                              .Î

< [hex]:
0000  03 00 01 00 00 00 0E 54  68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61   .......T his is a
0010  20 74 65 73 74 CE                                   testÎ

< [hex]:
0000  01 00 01 00 00 00 0B 00  14 00 28 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ..(.....
0010  00 00 CE                                           ..Î

< 20,40: Channel.close
waiting for 20,41
waiting for a new frame
```

The message does not seem to get delivered.

However, I have run these scripts on another virtual machine (Centos 6.2, Rabbit 3.1.3, PHP 5.4.3) and get the following from 'amqp_publisher.php':

```
< 60,40: Basic.publish
< [hex]:
0000  02 00 01 00 00 00 1A 00  3C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ <.......
0010  00 00 0E 90 00 0A 74 65  78 74 2F 70 6C 61 69 6E   .....te xt/plain
0020  02 CE                                              .Î

< [hex]:
0000  03 00 01 00 00 00 0E 54  68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61   .......T his is a
0010  20 74 65 73 74 CE                                   testÎ

< [hex]:
0000  01 00 01 00 00 00 0B 00  14 00 28 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ..(.....
0010  00 00 CE                                           ..Î

< 20,40: Channel.close
waiting for 20,41
waiting for a new frame
> 20,41: Channel.close_ok
< [hex]:
0000  01 00 00 00 00 00 0B 00  0A 00 32 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ..2.....
0010  00 00 CE                                           ..Î

< 10,50: Connection.close
waiting for 10,51
waiting for a new frame
> 10,51: Connection.close_ok
closing socket
```

And this from the consumer script:

```
< 60,20: Basic.consume 
waiting for 60,21
waiting for a new frame
> 60,21: Basic.consume_ok
waiting for any method
waiting for a new frame
> 60,60: Basic.deliver
waiting for a new frame
waiting for a new frame

--------
This is a test
--------
< [hex]:
0000  01 00 01 00 00 00 0D 00  3C 00 50 00 00 00 00 00   ........ <.P.....
0010  00 00 01 00 CE                                     ....Î

< 60,80: Basic.ack
```

In the successful example, I can see the delivery_mode of 2 reported back. What could be the reason that the message is not being delivered?

Answer (score 4):

[Matthias Radestock](http://www.springone2gx.com/conference/speaker/matthias_radestock) pointed me in the right direction by suggesting it looked like a resource issue, and advising I check the server logs. I found the following in /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit\@localhost.log :

```
=INFO REPORT==== 02-Sep-2013::12:48:48 ===
Disk free limit set to 1000MB

=INFO REPORT==== 02-Sep-2013::12:48:48 ===
Disk free space insufficient. Free bytes:588042240 Limit:1000000000

=WARNING REPORT==== 02-Sep-2013::12:48:48 ===
disk resource limit alarm set on node 'rabbit@localhost'.

**********************************************************
*** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***
**********************************************************
```

Created the file /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config and added the following:

```
[{rabbit, [{disk_free_limit, 100000000}]}].
```

Restarted RabbitMQ & now I can publish & consume as expected.